# how to run eclipse projects on a ubuntu server

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-16.04, bigdata

I installed eclipse in a server which is not opening at all. It seems this is not correct way to run eclipse in a server. Can anyone suggest me ways to run eclipse projects in a ubuntu server. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Eclipse is a development enviornment, you don't use it to run production code. Assuming this is Java you export the code as a jar and run that.

Comment: but every time if i want to do any modifications and run the project always then i have to follow same procedure,i mean running the jar file??

Comment: Eclipse provides lots of support for doing web development using a test server in Eclipse (see for example [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html)). Once the code is working you export it and use it in you live production server.

Comment: I am not running a web project, i am using an application client project for big data, while i am running in local everything is fine, but i am not getting how to run that type of projects in ubuntu server. Anyway thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I am executing a jar file in my server, when i am running it is executing but there is not output. this is the command i used java -jar Sqoo***.jar, no errors but no output also.what does it mean, can u tell me